# AWS CLI: Eror parsing parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-application-load-balancer

We are trying to create a listener rule with conditions-Host header in elastic load balancer by aws cli.

```
aws elbv2 create-rule 
--listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-south-1:123456789:listener/app/testing-alb/6sdfgsgs5fg45s4fg5sd \
--conditions test.com \
--priority 5 \
--actions arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-south-1:123456789:targetgroup/tgtest-1/hsdjif444225 \
--region ap-south-1 \
--output json
```

However, we got a error like this,

```
Error parsing parameter '--conditions': Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input:
test.com
        ^
```

Comment: Take a look at the examples [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/elbv2/create-rule.html#examples). `--conditions` needs to be in specific format.

Comment: can we pass a parameter to create a listener rule instead of using json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this inline, here is the correct syntax:

```
aws elbv2 create-rule \
--listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-south-1:123456789:listener/app/testing-alb/6sdfgsgs5fg45s4fg5sd \
--conditions '[{"Field":"host-header","HostHeaderConfig":{"Values":["test.com"]}}]' \
--priority 5 \
--actions Type=forward,TargetGroupArn=arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-south-1:123456789:targetgroup/tgtest-1/hsdjif444225 \
--region ap-south-1 \
--output json
```

Comment: Thank you @jellycsc this works as excepted.